# What does the US immigrant visa envelope contain?

Tags: usa, visa, immigration, greencard, documentation

A friend just entered the diversity visa lottery, and I've informed her about most of the process.

Something I do ask myself, however, is: what exactly does the sealed envelope you get from the embassy contain?

The concerned person has never been married, served in the military, been convicted or arrested...nothing, so she'll only need to provide the very "basic" documents.

With this in mind, my understanding is that she needs to provide the following:

- Medical exam
- 2 photographs
- High School diploma
- Full birth certificate
- Police certificate (which will be "empty")
- Bank account Statement (to prove she won't become a public charge)
- (Photocopy of passport's ID page? Not stated in the diversity visa section of the website, but is stated in the general immigrant visa section)

Will all of these be in the envelope, and will there be anything other than that?

In other words, what does the envelope actually contain?

Comment: I'm confused - you first ask about what the "envelope you *get*" contains, then you list a set of documents you *give*. Also - jumping the gun just a little ... the DV lottery you enter this year only happens next year and then there's a good chance you won't be selected ...

Comment: @brhans I know that, but the applicant has asked me to provide her as much info as possible, in case she **does** get selected. Also, I wonder if all the documents I listed, or anything besides those, will be in the envelope

Comment: still confused. Are you asking what you *get from* the embassy or what you *send to* the embassy.

Comment: @brhans Once the sealed envelope is issued by the embassy, what is actually inside it? My understanding is that it's *roughly* the docs you've sent to the embassy earlier, but I'd like to know more exactly

Comment: @Crazydre Why does that matter? It is a communication between two US government departments that happens to be done by having a third party carry an envelope. In the unlikely event that she wins the lottery, there will be documents she needs to send to get the visa, and documents, in addition to the envelope, she should have with her on arrival. Those lists of documents are what matters.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan We simply want to be aware.

Comment: According to people on the immihelp forums, it contains the full record from the consulate, all the paperwork.

Comment: I can't tell you what was in there, but it seemed like a bigger stack of paper than I gave them. I think I saw a printout of some information from the DS-260, and there were pages on top having a lot of text I did not write. The reason I can't tell you more is that the CBP officer seemed quite uninterested in reading anything beyond the top page.

Comment: Unofficially, here's what I've found so far: the envelope contains the immigrant petition and all supporting documents, including the Affidavit of Support, physical/medical records, interview results, police clearances, any waivers that may have been issued by USCIS to overcome any visa ineligibilities.